# Do I need a visa to exit the airport during a layover in the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, layovers

I plan to visit the USA on a B-1 (Visitor) visa. I will have a layover of seven hours in Paris's Charles de Gaulle (CDG) airport.  I want to visit Paris.

Being an Indian citizen, will I require **any kind of visa** for Paris?

Comment: @NateEldredge: not really a duplicate, he is not asking about transit - he wants to visit Paris. This is not even a scope of transit visa.

Comment: @GeorgeY. isn't that a layover, which is in the other one?

Comment: @MarkMayo the proposed dupe is about transiting airside and we don't seem to have a good question about exiting to the city in the Schengen area.

Comment: @MarkMayo: his question is not about transit/layover, he's basically asking, can I fly to Paris **and visit it** for a few hours?

Comment: @pnuts: no, it does not. See the #1 answer yourself: "*If you can enter the Schengen area, you can also transit there*". But OP questions is not whether he can transit, it is whether he can visit (and being Indian national, he cannot without visa, although he can transit without visa due to US visa). The thing is that the original question had "transit" stamped all over it, and it was closed because people thought it was about transit.

Answer (score 2):

In the original question (before our editing) you asked if you need a transit visa to leave the airport and visit Paris.

In Schengen area a **transit** visa would only allow you to transit through the airport, and would not allow you to leave the airport and visit the city. To visit the city you'd need a **short stay visa**, which is basically a typical "tourist" visa. And while you're exempted from having a transit visa (which Indian passport holders are required to have) due to having a US visa, you'd need a short stay visa if you want to visit Paris.

However please note that CDG is quite far from the city of Paris, and it will take you at least an hour (likely more) to get to the city after you clear the passport control - and this can take another hour. Considering that you'd have the same train and passport control on your way back from Paris - plus airport security on top of it - and that you'd have to be at your gate no later than 40 minutes before the flight to US, you don't have much time to spend there.